# AWS and Chef in local mode: use node cache from saved AMI instance on a new instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, autoscaling, amazon-ami

I am running chef 13+ on AWS Ubuntu in `local mode` via `EC2 UserData`.  I have a `common` role which installs/configures many common things for the organization.

Chef in local mode will create a `nodes` directory in the repo checkout.  It then creates a `private-IP.json` file that's used for cache.

Everything is fine, I image to an AMI and add to it the LaunchConfig for AutoScaling.

However, in AutoScaling I have to remove that `private-IP.json` file because I get a new private IP.  Thereby effectively deleting all the cache and work done before imaging.

One approach I have in mind is just to rename the file and use some `sed` magic to replace IP's and hostnames, but I am thinking there much be a better more Chef based approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally set the run list via the initial JSON `-j` or directly via `-r` for both `chef-solo` and local mode.